Generator of ELECTRA-Small model predicts same output for MASK tokens
I am trying to create a custom script that will be able to train the ELECTRA model from scratch. First I created a generator using code:
class ElectraForGenerating(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, hidden_size, vocab_size):
        super(ElectraForGenerating, self).__init__()
        config = ElectraConfig.from_json_file("./config.json")
        self.ElectraModel = ElectraModel(config)
        self.generator_predictions = torch.nn.Linear(hidden_size, vocab_size)
    def forward(self, input_ids, token_type_ids=None, position_ids=None):
        encoder_output = self.ElectraModel(input_ids)
        generator_predictions = self.generator_predictions(encoder_output.last_hidden_state)
        return generator_predictions

With the following config (1/4 of small model as recommended):
{
  "attention_probs_dropout_prob": 0.1,
  "hidden_size": 64,
  "intermediate_size": 256,
  "num_attention_heads": 1,
  "num_hidden_layers": 12,
  "embedding_size": 128,
  "hidden_act": "gelu",
  "hidden_dropout_prob": 0.1,
  "initializer_range": 0.02,
  "layer_norm_eps": 1e-12,
  "max_position_embeddings": 512,
  "type_vocab_size": 2,
  "vocab_size": 30522,
  "num_labels": 1,
  "model_type": "electra"
}

For this I created an AdamW optimizer and an LR scheduler:
optimizerGen = torch.optim.AdamW(generator.parameters(), lr=5e-4, betas=(0.9, 0.999), eps=1e-6, weight_decay=0.01)
schedulerGen = WarmupThenLinearDecayScheduler(optimizerGen, warmup_steps, 1000000, 1e-7, 5e-4, 0)

I prepare the data as recommended:

I will replace 15% of the tokens with [MASK]
Replace 10% of the [MASK] tokens with a random token
Replace 10% of the [MASK] tokens with the original token
Loss is calculated only for MASK tokens

After a bit of training, the model will achieve that it correctly overwrites the tokens that are not replaced by the [MASK] token, but always returns the same value for the whole MASK tokens instead of the correct tokens. So, for example, all [MASK] tokens should be replaced by token 0, etc., which is obviously wrong.
Is there anything else I need to set up specifically to make the generator work?
